# Realtime communication app backend

Tags: ios, real-time, openfire

I am developing a desktop application which will communicate with an iOS app and transfer/receive data in realtime. What is the best way to do this? Should I use something like OpenFire as the backend server?

Thanks.

Comment: You haven't given a lot of detail about what you are trying to achieve. Openfire is an XMPP "chat" server, so it may be suitable if that is what you want to transfer. If you want to transfer audio/video streams  then it isn't suitable.

Comment: I am going to transfer text data in real time. For e.g., send out an alert to a user that he needs to be someplace or update someone's gps location in realtime. So, I will be dealing with text data all the time. Yes, there will be audio/video streams but that won't be done through the OpenFire or any other realtime server. I will upload that using PHP and then send a push notification to all users asking them to tap on a link to download the video.

Comment: Or is jWebSocket a better solution compared to OpenFire?

Comment: Again, it is hard to say. Openfire deals with multiple clients and there are XMPP libraries on many platforms but requires you to install and configure the server. JWebSocket is a lower level networking class that requires you to do a lot more work with formatting and routing your messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going with OpenFire. OpenFire has a lot of options starting from private messaging to conferencing to email notifications using plugins. Overall, it is more flexible than any of the other solutions out there.

Answer (score 1):

What about using Bonjour? This project on GitHub will help you a lot.

https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTBonjour